# The $2N$ balls problem

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

Le $N$ be an integer, $N\ge 1$.
Suppose we have $2N$ balls, numbered by pairs from $1$ to $N$.
So we have $2$ balls numbered $1$, $2$ balls numbered $2$, etc. until $N$.

For which value of $N$ can we arrange these $2N$ balls so that between any $2$ balls numbered $k$, $1\le k\lt N$, there is exactly $k$ balls ? For example, $3-1-2-1-3-2$ is a correct arrangement for $N=3$.

Additional question : for such values of $N$, expose the method to construct such an arrangement

Comment: You don't look for some method, you look for an efficient method to arrange $2N$ numbers.

Comment: what is the source of this?

Comment: The source of the problem is a very old issue of a french magazine called La Recherche.

Answer (score 0):

This is the *Langford's cubes* problem, although the "cubes" part is something of my own memory and not found in the literature. The number of solutions for each $N$ is [OEIS A014552](https://oeis.org/A014552); in particular there are solutions iff $N\equiv0,3\bmod4$.

Comment: I think it's known as Langford pairings or Langford's sequences in common literature